# removing rows from a SELECT based on columns in a different table

Tags: sql, mysql, database, join, rdbms

I'm pretty much looking for a way to filter out rows from a `SELECT` of one table based on certain values in rows of another table.

I'm experimenting with the example structure below. I've got a table of blog post content (one row per blog post), and another table of metadata about the posts (one row per key-value pair; each row with a column associating it with a blog post; many rows per blog post). I want to pull a row of `posts` only if there exists no rows in `metadata` where `metadata.pid=posts.pid AND metadata.k='optout'`. That is, for the example structure below, I just want to get back the `posts.id=1` row.

(Based on what I've tried) `JOIN`s don't end up removing the posts which have some metadata where `metadata.k='optout'`, because the other row of metadata for that `pid` means it makes it into the results.

```
mysql> select * from posts;
+-----+-------+--------------+
| pid | title | content      |
+-----+-------+--------------+
|   1 | Foo   | Some content |
|   2 | Bar   | More content |
|   3 | Baz   | Something    |
+-----+-------+--------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from metadata;
+------+-----+--------+-----------+
| mdid | pid | k      | v         |
+------+-----+--------+-----------+
|    1 |   1 | date   | yesterday |
|    2 |   1 | thumb  | img.jpg   |
|    3 |   2 | date   | today     |
|    4 |   2 | optout | true      |
|    5 |   3 | date   | tomorrow  |
|    6 |   3 | optout | true      |
+------+-----+--------+-----------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

A subquery can give me the inverse of what I want:

```
mysql> select posts.* from posts where pid = any (select pid from metadata where k = 'optout');
+-----+-------+--------------+
| pid | title | content      |
+-----+-------+--------------+
|   2 | Bar   | More content |
|   3 | Baz   | Something    |
+-----+-------+--------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

...but using `pid != any (...)` gives me all 3 of the rows in posts, cause every single `pid` has a metadata row where `k!='optout'`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like you want to do a `LEFT JOIN` and then check for results in which the value of the joined table is `NULL`, indicating that no such joined record exists.

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM posts 
LEFT JOIN metadata ON (posts.pid = metadata.pid AND metadata.k = 'optout')
WHERE metadata.mdid IS NULL;
```

This will select any row from the table `posts` for which no corresponding `metadata` row exists with a value of `k = 'optout'`.

edit: Worth noting that this is a key property of a left join and would not work with a regular join; a left join will always return values from the first table, even if no matching values exist in the joined table(s), allowing you to perform selections based on the absence of those rows.

edit 2: Let's clarify what's happening here with respect to the `LEFT JOIN` versus the `JOIN` (which I refer to as an `INNER JOIN` for clarity but is interchangable in MySQL).

Suppose you run either of these two queries:

```
SELECT posts.*, metadata.mdid, metadata.k, metadata.v 
FROM posts 
INNER JOIN metadata ON posts.pid = metadata.pid;
```

or

```
SELECT posts.*, metadata.mdid, metadata.k, metadata.v 
FROM posts 
LEFT JOIN metadata ON posts.pid = metadata.pid;
```

Both queries produce the following result set:

```
+-----+-------+--------------+------+-------+-----------+
| pid | title | content      | mdid | k     | v         |
+-----+-------+--------------+------+-------+-----------+
|   1 | Foo   | Some content |    1 | date  | yesterday |
|   1 | Foo   | Some content |    2 | thumb | img.jpg   |
+-----+-------+--------------+------+-------+-----------+
```

Now, let's suppose we modify the query to add the extra criteria for "optout" that was mentioned. First, the `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT posts.*, metadata.mdid, metadata.k, metadata.v 
FROM posts 
INNER JOIN metadata ON (posts.pid = metadata.pid AND metadata.k = "optout");
```

As expected, this returns no results:

```
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Now, changing that to a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT posts.*, metadata.mdid, metadata.k, metadata.v 
FROM posts 
LEFT JOIN metadata ON (posts.pid = metadata.pid AND metadata.k = "optout");
```

This DOES produce a result set:

```
+-----+-------+--------------+------+------+------+
| pid | title | content      | mdid | k    | v    |
+-----+-------+--------------+------+------+------+
|   1 | Foo   | Some content | NULL | NULL | NULL |
+-----+-------+--------------+------+------+------+
```

The difference between an `INNER JOIN` and a `LEFT JOIN` is that an `INNER JOIN` will only return a result if rows from BOTH joined tables match. In a `LEFT JOIN`, matching rows from the first table will ALWAYS be returned, regardless of whether anything is found to join to. In a lot of cases it doesn't matter which one you use, but it's important to choose the right one so as not to get unexpected results down the line.

So in this case, the suggested query of:

```
SELECT posts.*, metadata.mdid, metadata.k, metadata.v 
LEFT JOIN metadata ON (posts.pid = metadata.pid AND metadata.k = 'optout')
WHERE metadata.mdid IS NULL;
```

Will return the same result set as above:

```
+-----+-------+--------------+------+------+------+
| pid | title | content      | mdid | k    | v    |
+-----+-------+--------------+------+------+------+
|   1 | Foo   | Some content | NULL | NULL | NULL |
+-----+-------+--------------+------+------+------+
```

Hopefully that clears it up! Joins are a great thing to learn about, having a full understanding of when to use which one is a very good thing.

Comment: So let me see if I get this... for a post with optout, the subquery matches a metadata row, so the metadata.mdid isn't null, so it doesn't get selected. But a post without optout, the subquery doesn't match a row so the right side gets padded with nulls, so the where clause is true.

Comment: I've added another section to the answer related to how the join is working, that should clear up any gray areas with it. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like

```
select  p.* 
from    posts p
where   NOT EXISTS (
                        select  pid 
                        from    metadata 
                        where   k = 'optout' 
                        and     pid = p.pid
                    )
```

Comment: FYI giving the checkmark to the other answer cause on 36000 rows the left join is .1 sec faster...

Comment: On a small result set the two queries should perform about the same. However, when you use `EXISTS` or `NOT EXISTS` with a subquery, it will need to compute the subquery table and copy it to a temporary table. So as your result sets grow it may become a large performance bottleneck. I wouldn't avoid it entirely, sometimes it makes things much easier to read/understand than a complicated join -- you just have to be aware of the type of result set it may eventually produce.

Comment: It certainly makes more sense to me right off the bat than a join, but that's just cause EXISTS is easier to grok than JOINs are... Good to know about the potential for a bottleneck.